# Why does the appearance of error messages in my Flutter app not look good when I have a 'TextFormField' inside a 'Card' widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have a 'TextFormField' inside a 'Card' widget in my Flutter app. However, when an in-app error occurs (triggered by the user), the appearance of the error message is not as desired. Here's the relevant code:

```
 Form(
                    key: _form,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        // email textfield
                        Card(
                          //surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 5,
                          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            enabled: !_isAuthenticating,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            controller: _emailController,
                            onTapOutside: (e) =>
                                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                            autocorrect: false,
                            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20,
                                vertical: 20,
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                borderSide:
                                    const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Email',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null ||
                                  value.trim().isEmpty ||
                                  !value.contains('@')) {
                                return 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                              }

                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              _enteredEmail = value!;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),

                        const SizedBox(height: 20),

                        // password textfield
                        Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            enabled: !_isAuthenticating,
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: _passwordVisible,
                            onTapOutside: (e) =>
                                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.key),
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20,
                                vertical: 20,
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide:
                                    const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Password',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  _passwordVisible
                                      ? Icons.visibility_off
                                      : Icons.visibility,
                                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.trim().length < 8) {
                                //_passwordError =
                                return 'Password must be at least 8 characters long.';
                                //_passwordError;
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              _enteredPassword = value!;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

[[image: I do not want the 'red line' above the error message, I know its because of the 'TextFormField']]

I'm a beginner in Flutter, and even though I attempted to address the issue with the guidance from ChatGPT, unfortunately, I wasn't able to resolve it. Can you please provide further assistance or guidance to help me achieve the desired appearance for error messages inside my 'Card' widget, without the red line?

It would be great if I could get it to look like this: [[image: I would not mind if the color is red but I just do not want the red line]]

In the error scenario, I don't want the red line above the error message, and I'd like the error message to be displayed outside the 'Card' widget.

How can I achieve this appearance without the red line and with the error message inside the 'Card' widget?